# my segue is not working

Tags: swift, segue, uialertcontroller

I have a button that if user click on it it must show another vc and it's working properly until I add UIAlertController which it's getting data from user and after user click done on alertaction nothing happens
this is my code:

```
    @IBAction func DfsClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "DFS?", message: "Please input DFS depth:", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (_) in
        if let field = alertController.textFields?[0] {
            // store your data
            self.depth = Int(field.text!)!
            print(self.depth)
            Puzzle.AnswerNode = dfs(inputdepth: self.depth,SortedPuzzle:self.SortedPuzzle)
        } else {
            // user did not fill field
        }
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Default is 2"
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    }
    alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method to perform segue, inside confirm action block

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: <Identifier>, sender: <Any?>)
```